# how can I remove some unwanted characters in dictionary values

Tags: python, nlp

I extracted some search keywords and their corresponding text and put them into a dictionary using python. A sample of dictionary looks as follows:

```
{'ID': 'ID', 'HE': 'Q1 - lth', 'LT': 'Q2 - La tor', 'HIP': 'Q3a - hh sure', 'MHBP': 'Q3.1.a -  pressure ', 'DITE': 'Q3b - Dates'}
```

how can I remove all the Q and the letters to - (including - )?

Output should looks like :

> {'ID': 'ID', 'HE': 'lth', 'LT': 'La tor', 'HIP': 'hh sure', 'MHBP': 'pressure ', 'DITE': 'Dates'}

Comment: For this specific case something like `your_dict = {key:value.split(' - ')[-1] for key, value in your_dict.items()}`. Note there are some extra spaces around `pressure`. You may need to strip these as well by using `value.split(' - ')[-1].strip()`

Comment: *"I know that I have to use a regular expression"* No, you don't. You'll never *have to* use a regular expression.

Comment: I have no idea why my question got negative score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(^\s*Q.*\-\s*)")
d = {'ID': 'ID', 'HE': 'Q1 - lth', 'LT': 'Q2 - La tor', 
     'HIP': 'Q3a - hh sure', 'MHBP': 'Q3.1.a -  pressure ', 'DITE': 'Q3b - Dates'}
d = {k:pattern.sub("", v) for (k, v) in d.items()}
d
```